# WCF restful service: How to send long string parameters in POST requests?

Tags: c#, post, wcf-rest

I have this kind of method in my resful wcf service:
ServiceContract-

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "CreateTask?t={token}&title={title}&aun={assigneeUsername}&inst={instructions}&tnum={taskNumber}&pr={priority}&ud={userData}")]
Stream CreateTask(string token, string title, string assigneeUsername, string instructions, string taskNumber,
                        string priority, string userData);
```

Service class:

```
public Stream CreateTask(string token, string title, string assigneeUsername, string instructions, string taskNumber,
                        string priority, string userData)
{...}
```

Some parameters can be very long strings (~5000) and I don't want them to be part of the query string, maybe to send some of them as FormUrlEncodedContent.

How can I send some of the paramets as part of the URL and the others as content/ in the body?
Can my operation contract look somthing like that?:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "CreateTask?t={token}")]
Stream CreateTask(string token, string title, string assigneeUsername, string instructions, string taskNumber,
                        string priority, string userData);
```

How should my client code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed in the client side to send the values in json format as HttpContent:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/MyService/Tasks.svc/");

var url = string.Format("CreateTask?t={0}&ud={1}", token, userData);

var myObject = (dynamic)new JObject();
myObject.title = title;
myObject.assigneeUsername = assigneeUsername;
myObject.instructions = instructions;
myObject.taskNumber = taskNumber;
myObject.priority = priority;

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(myObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```